# How can I use chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename to change downloaded file names if the files have extension of jpg or png?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How can I use [chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename) to change downloaded file names if the files have extension of JPG or PNG?

I am looking at the example here:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, __suggest) {
  function suggest(filename, conflictAction) {
    __suggest({filename: filename,
               conflictAction: conflictAction,
               conflict_action: conflictAction});
  }
  var rules = localStorage.rules;
  try {
    rules = JSON.parse(rules);
  } catch (e) {
    localStorage.rules = JSON.stringify([]);
  }
  for (var index = 0; index < rules.length; ++index) {
    var rule = rules[index];
    if (rule.enabled && matches(rule, item)) {
      if (rule.action == 'overwrite') {
        suggest(item.filename, 'overwrite');
      } else if (rule.action == 'prompt') {
        suggest(item.filename, 'prompt');
      } else if (rule.action == 'js') {
        eval(rule.action_js);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

This is confusing. How does [chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename) from above detect the name of the file? And once it detects, how did it change the file? Can anyone break down what these codes mean above?

Ref: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples

Answer (score 2):

- As soon as the filename is determined `onDeterminingFilename` event
  is triggered upon which a callback function is called and it takes 2
  parameters

  1. `item` object which contains data such as download id, url, filename, referrer etc. (see
     https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#type-DownloadItem)
  2. __suggest which must be called to pass suggestion either synchronously or asynchronously.
- A suggest function is defined which will be used to call `__suggest`
  based on the specific rule
- All the rules are accessed from the local memory and a `for` loop runs
  to iterate across them.
- For each iteration based on the `action` data in the `rule` the
  suggest function is called with specific `filename` and
  `conflictAction`.

Basically the filename is aceessed using `item.filename` and a new filename is suggested by calling `__suggest` where the value for the key `filename` contains the new filename.